# how to calculate recall fast and correct with duplicate document id's python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have two tsv data files (gold and results) with four columns and I would like to calculate the recall score. Here is the format of the gold file:

```
(doc1)  173 174 mike
(doc2)  189 194 sara
(doc2)  189 194 mike    
(doc2)  200 207 car
```

format of the resluts file:

```
(doc1)  173 174 mike
(doc2)  189 194 mike    
(doc2)  200 207 car
```

and here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division    
def eval():
        tp=0 #true positives
        fn=0 #false negatives
        gold=[]
        results=[]

        with open('/path/to/gold.tsv', 'rb') as goldFile, open('/path/to/results.tsv', 'rb') as f:
            for l in goldFile:
                parts = l.decode('utf-8').split('\t')
                try:
                   gold.append((parts[0], parts[3]))
                except:pass

            for line in f:
                cols = line.decode('utf-8').split('\t')
                try:
                   results.append((cols[0], cols[3]))
                except:pass       

        for i,j in gold:
            doc = []
            for docid in results:
               if results[0] == i:
                  doc.append(docid) 

            for k, v in doc:
                if j == v:
                    tp += 1
                    gold.remove((i,j))
                    results.remove((i,j))
                    continue
            gold.remove((i,j))
            fn += 1

        return float(tp)/(tp+fn)

    print(eval())
```

The output is:

```
0.0
```

`Recall` should be `0.75` in the above case, what am I doing wrong? And how to calculate more efficiently? I tried with dictionaries but since I have duplicate documents id's that is not possible. I'd really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tp` and `fn` are both integers so the result will be an integer. try with `return float(tp)/(tp+fn)`

Comment: @gogaz you're absolutely right! but it still game me 0.0. will edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: `if results[0] == i:` do you mean `docid[0] == i`?

Comment: @khachik I want to see if the first value in the results tuple the same as the first value in gold tuple. I want to check if they have the same doc id. I'm sure there is amore efficient way to do what I want. Thank you for the help